# How can I control the path between two pins inside circuitikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, tikz-path

I have created my custom electric component named `myIC` using the `circuitikz.sty` library. `myIC` has three pins labeled `PinA`, `PinB`, `PinC` and a default label `myIClabel`. I defined this component within the `pgfdeclareshape` environment, allowing me to easily incorporate it into a `circuitikz` environment.

**Question**: How can I modify the path to follow the dotted blue line instead of the black line? Note, that the black line has been created by this command: `\draw (myIC1.PinC) -| (myIC2.PinA);`. See the output screenshot below

**CODE**:

```
\documentclass[border=0cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{circuitikz}

\pgfdeclareshape{myIC}{
    
    % define saved anchor
    % ----------------------------------------
    \anchor{center}{\pgfpointorigin}
    
    % define Connectors relative to the center
    % ----------------------------------------
    % Pin A:
    \savedanchor\myICpinA{\pgfpoint{-30}{10}}
    \anchor{PinA}{\myICpinA}
    % Pin B:
    \savedanchor\myICpinB{\pgfpoint{-30}{-10}}
    \anchor{PinB}{\myICpinB}
    % Pin C:
    \savedanchor\myICpinC{\pgfpoint{30}{0}}
    \anchor{PinC}{\myICpinC}
    
    \foregroundpath{
        
        \pgfpathrectanglecorners{\pgfpoint{-30}{-30}}{\pgfpoint{30}{30}}
        \pgfusepath{draw}
        
        \pgftext[left,  at={\myICpinA}]{PinA}
        \pgftext[left,  at={\myICpinB}]{PinB}
        \pgftext[right, at={\myICpinC}]{PinC}
        
    }
    
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
        % Instance of the custom component in red
        \draw (0,0) node[myIC, red] (myIC1) {};
        % Another instance in green
        \draw (3,0) node[myIC, green] (myIC2) {};
        
        % connecting pins
        \draw (myIC1.PinC) -| (myIC2.PinA);
        
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

**OUTPUT**:

[image]

Comment: If you used code from elsewhere, including other questions on this site, please attribute and provide links. (SE's licence requires this, but it also makes it a lot easier for people to help.)

Comment: For you question: use the `paths.ortho` tikzlibrary. Or just do it manually: draw a bit and then do `-|` or `|-`. The library lets you do e.g. `-|-`, `|-|` etc. https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-ext

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either do it manually: draw a bit and then `-|` or `|-` or you can use the recent `ext.paths.ortho` library.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{ext.paths.ortho}

\pgfdeclareshape{myIC}{
  % define saved anchor
  \anchor{center}{\pgfpointorigin}
  % Pins
  \savedanchor\myICpinA{\pgfpoint{-30}{10}}
  \anchor{PinA}{\myICpinA}
  \savedanchor\myICpinB{\pgfpoint{-30}{-10}}
  \anchor{PinB}{\myICpinB}
  \savedanchor\myICpinC{\pgfpoint{30}{0}}
  \anchor{PinC}{\myICpinC}
  \foregroundpath{
    \pgfpathrectanglecorners{\pgfpoint{-30}{-30}}{\pgfpoint{30}{30}}
    \pgfusepath{draw}
    \pgftext[left,  at={\myICpinA}]{PinA}
    \pgftext[left,  at={\myICpinB}]{PinB}
    \pgftext[right, at={\myICpinC}]{PinC}
    % my static label
    \pgftext[center, at={\pgfpoint{0}{35}}]{\small\textcolor{black}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/mm/myLabel}}}
  }
}
\pgfqkeys{/mm}{myLabel/.initial=myIClabel}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
  % Instance of the custom component in red
  \draw (0,0) node[myIC, red, /mm/myLabel=coch] (myIC1) {};
  % Another instance in green
  \draw (3,0) node[myIC, green, /mm/myLabel=gwyrdd] (myIC2) {};
  % Yet another instance in blue
  \draw (6,0) node[myIC, blue, /mm/myLabel=glas] (myIC3) {};
  \draw (myIC1.PinC) -|- (myIC2.PinA);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: turn-turn-turn auto-path with ext.paths.ortho]

Comment: thanks a lot. exactly what i was looking for. but how do i get `\usetikzlibrary{ext.paths.ortho}`? best regards

Comment: @MarcoMoldenhauer The link to CTAN is in my comment on your question above. Or just update your TeX distribution and you'll have it.

Comment: Thank you very much; everything is functioning as anticipated.

Comment: @MarcoMoldenhauer Thanks for letting me know.